# In the React tutorial, why does the appearance not change if I comment out the clear fix?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm following the [React tutorial](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html) and have a question about their [starter code](https://codepen.io/gaearon/pen/oWWQNa?editors=0010):

```
class Square extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <button className="square">
        {/* TODO */}
      </button>
    );
  }
}

class Board extends React.Component {
  renderSquare(i) {
    return <Square />;
  }

  render() {
    const status = 'Next player: X';

    return (
      <div>
        <div className="status">{status}</div>
        <div className="board-row">
          {this.renderSquare(0)}
          {this.renderSquare(1)}
          {this.renderSquare(2)}
        </div>
        <div className="board-row">
          {this.renderSquare(3)}
          {this.renderSquare(4)}
          {this.renderSquare(5)}
        </div>
        <div className="board-row">
          {this.renderSquare(6)}
          {this.renderSquare(7)}
          {this.renderSquare(8)}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Game extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="game">
        <div className="game-board">
          <Board />
        </div>
        <div className="game-info">
          <div>{/* status */}</div>
          <ol>{/* TODO */}</ol>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

// ========================================

ReactDOM.render(
  <Game />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

with the following CSS, in which I've commented out the `.board-row:after` directives:

```
body {
  font: 14px "Century Gothic", Futura, sans-serif;
  margin: 20px;
}

ol, ul {
  padding-left: 30px;
}

/* .board-row:after {
  clear: both;
  content: "";
  display: table;
} */

.status {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.square {
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  float: left;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 34px;
  height: 34px;
  margin-right: -1px;
  margin-top: -1px;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 34px;
}

.square:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.kbd-navigation .square:focus {
  background: #ddd;
}

.game {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.game-info {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

What I don't understand is after commenting out these directives,

```
.board-row:after {
  clear: both;
  content: "";
  display: table;
}
```

which appear to be an implementation of the "Easy Clearing Method" described in [All About Floats](https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/), I still see the squares organized in an 'array' as they originally were, and not all in a row. Since the default display property is `inline`, I would expect all 9 squares to displayed in a single row without the 'easy clearing method'. Why does the appearance not change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tl;dr use [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

---

You seem to have misunderstandings in a lot of different places.

1. This problem isn't specific to React, it's a problem with the HTML and CSS you're using. You're referring to `.board-row:after` as a "directive", but it's really just a simple CSS rule
2. Different HTML elements have different default CSS property values. You're using `div` elements, which have a default `display` value of `block`, which means that it will drop to the next line, instead of appearing "inline" with its siblings
3. A couple years ago, the only way to achieve what you're trying to do with elements that are set to `display: block` was to use floats. Applying `float: left` to a series of divs would cause them to appear next to eachother on the same line. Floats, however, can be painful to work with; one pain point is that in order for a parent HTML element to be aware of elements inside it that use floats, you needed to "clear" your floats by adding an element at the end with `clear: both`. That's where the clearfix trick came into play. Nowadays, however, [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) is the way to achieve what you're trying to do.